# Does receiver stores its streaming content in one where the executor is running?

Tags: apache-spark

Lets say there are  3 executors (ex1, ex2, ex3). In one executor(ex1) lets say receiver is running, now what happens when the data comes in that source.
Lets say a data is arrived in a kafka topic say "topic1", now the receiver running in ex1 will consume that data arrived in the topic right? Now where is that data stored?

1. Is it stored in that executor ex1 itself?
2. What if that data is too huge? Does it breaks it down and distributes it over to other executors?

Lets say a capacity of 10gb each executor(ex1, ex2, ex3). And a data arrived say 15gb (hypothetical assumption) now what happens to ex1. Will it fail or it will be handled? If handles how will it handle? Does it distributes over the cluster. If it distributes over the cluster, how will the foreachRDD fits into picture if in a batch only one rdd is formed. As if it distributes by breaking up, now it is more then one rdd in cluster right for that particular batch?

3. How many receivers run in spark job? Does it depends on the number of input sources? If spark is reading from 4 different kafka topics, does it mean that 4 different receivers will run separately in different executors? What if there are only 2 executors and 4 kafka topics/sources?In that case will 4 different receivers run in these two executors evenly? What if the sources are of odd number? IF two executors and 3 kafka sources, then is it that in one of the executors there will be two? What if one of the executors dies? How will it get recovered?

Answer (score 0):

1. Is it stored in that executor ex1 itself?

Yes all the data fetched by the Spark Driver is pushed to executor for further processing.

2. What if that data is too huge? Does it breaks it down and
   distributes it over to other executors?

The data is Hash partitioned once read by Spark receiver and then distributed among the executor fairly. If still you a data skew try adding a Custom partitioner and repartition the data.

3. How many receivers run in spark job? Does it depends on the number of input sources? If spark is reading from 4 different kafka topics, does it mean that 4 different receivers will run separately in different executors? What if there are only 2 executors and 4 kafka topics/sources?In that case will 4 different receivers run in these two executors evenly? What if the sources are of odd number? IF two executors and 3 kafka sources, then is it that in one of the executors there will be two? What if one of the executors dies? How will it get recovered?

There only one single receiver (i.e. one or multiple topics) which does the Kafka offset management. It hands over range of offsets per topic to Spark executor and Spark executor reads the data directly from Kafka. If anyone of the executor dies all the stages of it are re-executed from the last successful saved stage. 
The Spark load distribution is not based size of data but on the count of events.
Guidelines say that if there are N partitions for a topic then Spark should have 2N executors to achieve optimum CPU resource utilization.

You should find more details on below link,
https://blog.cloudera.com/reading-data-securely-from-apache-kafka-to-apache-spark/